# php - Get radio button name attributes value

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a stupid question but im really not sure how to tackle this, perhaps im overthinking. I need to retrieve both the name attributes value and the value attributes value. Have a look at img below:

```
echo'<input type="radio" name="'.$eventId[].'" value="'.$team1.'">';
```

[image]
[image]

The name contains the event_id and the value contains user selection. I need the name Ids value to insert event Id into db along with user selection.

I know how to retrieve the rad value attribute but not sure about the name, maybe Im overthinking it or need to change my logic. Any ideas?

Comment: An ID attribute would have had to begin with a letter as per the HTML 4.01 W3C specification, however since the NAME attribute of input elements, this restriction does not apply.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If user select Australia radio button than in PHP you will get value 'Australia' but you want the value 'Australia_80' to store in db. Change all your radio button values and names like

```
<input type="radio" value="Australia_80" name="getRadio">
<input type="radio" value="Canada_81" name="getRadio">
```

Comment: If you can put your full code than it help to understand better!!